# Make LLDB reinterpret address as pointer to an object whose type is a template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, lldb

When debugging, I have an address into memory and know the type of the object that resides at that address, and I want the debugger to display that instance of the object. This can be done via print command for types that are not templates but seems to fail for types that are an instantiation of a template.

See this example code:

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    X() {
        printf("a\n");
    }
};

class Y
{
public:
    Y() {
        printf("a\n");
    }
};



int main(void)
{
    X<int> x;
    Y y;

    return 1;
}
```

when I run the program, break in main and try to interpret random valid address into pointers to both X and Y objects, the former fails:

```
(lldb) p *(Y*)0x0000000100000ee6
(Y) $0 = {}
(lldb) p *(X<int>*)0x0000000100000ee6
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
error: use of undeclared identifier 'X'
error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
error: expected expression
```

Is there any way how to do this in lldb?
(edit: Mac OS X lldb-360.1.65 and lldb-310.2.37)

Answer (score 5):

The debug information for C++ doesn't currently represent templates in the abstract, it only talks about the specific template instantiations present in your program.  But lldb's expression command uses a real C++ parser (clang) which when parsing an expression like the one you tried, wants first to see X as an abstract template.  Since we don't know about them we can't fulfill clang's type request for X, and - that's why the error you see is "undeclared identifier X".

You can work around this by making a typedef for the pointer types you want to cast this way.  That's not very satisfactory, because you have to have done it up front, AND you have to use the typedef in your code somewhere because - to keep the size of debug info manageable - clang doesn't emit debug information for types that aren't used.  But it does work, e.g. I add to your sample code:

```
typedef X<int> * x_int_ptr;
```

and then later on in main:

```
  x_int_ptr bar = (x_int_ptr) &x;
```

to make sure it gets recorded, then in ldb I can do:

```
(lldb) expr *((x_int_ptr) 0x00007fff5fbff798)
(X<int>) $1 = {}
```